# How to show the comment body in reply comment based on parent_id

Tags: php, laravel

Actually, i confused to ask about the title for my problem.

i have the table comment like this

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('comments')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->integer('commentable_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('commentable_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('commentable_type');
            $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and my relationship to show reply from parent_id in **Comment Model** like this.

```
public function myreplyfrom()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Comment::class,'parent_id')->select('body');
}
```

i show body comment in blade like this

```
@foreach($mycomments as $comment)                        
    <p> Reply from Comment-> {{ $comment->myreplyfrom }} </p>    
@endforeach
```

my comment table like this
[image: my comment table]

and my comment dashboard like this
[image: my comment dashboard]

what i've done is right to show the body of comment, but i want to remove `{"body"}`, so just comment without array and field title.

the result i expected is
`Reply from Comment-> sdsds` and `Reply from Comment-> woww`

how to fix my problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this in view for comment body of reply

`@foreach($mycomments as $comment)

    <p> Reply from Comment-> {{ $comment->myreplyfrom->body }} </p>

@endforeach`

Comment: i've error `Trying to get property of non-object`. you can see relationship

Comment: `{{ $comment->myreplyfrom ? $comment->myreplyfrom->body : 'NO REPLY'  }}` use like this.... as it is possible that comment may have parent id or may not

Comment: it is because your comment with id 1 do not have parent id so use ternary operator mentioned in above comment

Comment: yes it's work. it's my fault. thanks for your explanation. i must check if there are no parent id.